# How to properly use call() in D3 to bind drag behavior?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to create a rectangle and let it listen to a drag event. According to the documentation I have to append the 'rect' first and call the `dragR(event)`.

```
d3.select('#rectangle').on('click', function(){ new Rectangle(); });

function Rectangle(preloaded = false, box = []) {

    .......
    var dragR = d3.behavior.drag().on('drag', dragRect);

    function dragRect() {
      var e = d3.event;
      for(var i = 0; i < self.rectData.length; i++){
        d3.select(self.rectangleElement[0][0])
          .attr('x', self.rectData[i].x += e.dx )
          .attr('y', self.rectData[i].y += e.dy );
      }
      rect.style('cursor', 'move');
      updateRect();
    }

    rectangleElement = d3.select('svg').append('rect').attr('class', 'rectangle').call(dragR);

}
```

Now my question is that what exactly is `rectangleElement`? Is it a function or anything? Can anyone explain what is the workflow of this code? Also, what if I want to bind another event(said click) to it?

Comment: Why did you edit your code after receiving two answer which properly explain the questions you posted. Those extra three lines of code substantially change the entire code by putting it in a completely different context. That is a whole different story...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: @altocumulus answer brings more details on methods result :)

> what exactly is `rectangleElement`

`rectangleElement` is a [d3 Selection](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection), containing your `rect` svg element.

> Can anyone explain what is the workflow of this code

```
var dragR = d3.behavior.drag().on('drag', dragRect);
```

With this line, you are defining a [d3 Drag behavior](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Drag-Behavior.md), that creates event listeners for drag events (and touch). With the `.on()` method, you attach handlers to the event. Here, you attach the function `dragRect` on the `drag` event. The `drag` event is the event fired while you are dragging an element (you also have `dragStart` and `dragEnd`). This line just define the behavior, this is not linked yet to your `rect` element.

```
rectangleElement = d3.select('svg').append('rect').attr('class', 'rectangle').call(dragR);
```

On this line, you are creating your `rect` element. You select first the first matched `svg` element and then you add a `rect` inside it, add the class `rectangle` on your new created `rect` and finally attach the drag listener to your `rect` element ([`call()` function doc](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_call)).

```
function dragRect() {
  var e = d3.event;
  for(var i = 0; i < self.rectData.length; i++){
     d3.select(self.rectangleElement[0][0])
     .attr('x', self.rectData[i].x += e.dx )
     .attr('y', self.rectData[i].y += e.dy );
  }
     rect.style('cursor', 'move');
     updateRect();
  }
```

This is your handler for your `drag` event, this function will be called every time the `drag` event is fired. This function uses variables you did not put on your question, but looks like this change the x/y attributes of the `rect` and then move it.

> Also what if I want it to bind another event(said click)

There is multiple ways: you can attach a click handler when you create your `rect` element:

```
d3.select('svg')
    .append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'rectangle')
    .on('click', function(){ console.log('clicked'); })
    .call(dragR);
```

Or attach it later by selecting your `rect` element:

```
d3.select('rect.rectangle')
    .on('click', function(){ console.log('clicked'); })
```

Here is the [`on()` documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Selections.md#on) (for d3v3)

Comment: Darn, you beat me to it! Now I spent the better part of an hour writing up an answer very similar to yours ;-) I received no notification, that yours was already up. Anyways, good job!

Comment: 1. why you call that a selection while it has a call() in the end of that line?
2. the code i provide is in a function(just updated) how can i get the rect after the click event. Said update the value like `this.rectData`

Comment: @pwan 1)The `call()` method on d3.Selection returns the selection itself (to allow chaining selection methods). The Selection is a d3 concept, a kind of wrapper for your elements allowing you to call d3 methods. 2) Inside your click handler, you can get the clicked element directly with `this`, and then do `d3.select(this).someSelectionMethod(...)`. You can still select the rect element with `d3.select('rect.rectangle')`.

Comment: @altocumulus Your answer brings more details on some points, I will update my answer to point on yours :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, by your use of `d3.behavior.drag()` we can tell, that you are still using D3 v3 (this would be `d3.drag()` in v4 amongst other subtle differences).

---

The code you provided comprises three parts needed to set up the [drag behavior](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Drag-Behavior.md) on an SVG element.

**1. The drag behavior itself**

```
var dragR = d3.behavior.drag().on('drag', dragRect);
```

This is the D3 way of handling drag gestures on elements by automatically creating event listeners for drag events. Calling `.on()` on this behavior will register a handler function (namely `dragRect`), which will be triggered by the events it was registered for (`drag` in your case).

**2. The handler function**

```
function dragRect() {
  // ...
}
```

This function will be called for every event fired by a drag gesture on the element the drag behavior was applied to. In this function you will be doing all the stuff, i.e. data manipulation, DOM updates et cetera, that are needed to graphically react to the drag gesture.

**3. Applying the drag behavior to a selection**

```
rectangleElement = d3.select('svg').append('rect').attr('class', 'rectangle').call(dragR);
```

After creating a drag behavior instance and specifying a proper event handler function you can apply this behavior to a D3 selection. Or, in the words of the [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Drag-Behavior.md#drag):

> Once constructed, you can apply the drag behavior to selected elements
>   using selection.call

Looking at the documentation for [`selection.call()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Selections.md#call) answers your question what the return value of this function is:

> The call operator always returns the current selection, regardless of
>   the return value of the specified function.

Therefore, `rectangleElement` will hold a reference to a D3 selection containing the `<rect>` which was previously appended.

---

Since you asked for it, in v3 a selection will be an array of arrays, as can be seen in the handler function, where the element is accessed as `self.rectangleElement[0][0]`). At a beginner's level, however, you should not be concerned too much about the implementation details. It will suffice to know it's a D3 selection, that features a well defined API.

---

Because `rectangleElement` is a D3 selection, you can easily register more event handlers on it by chaining further calls to [`selection.on()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Selections.md#on):

```
rectangleElement.on("click", function(d) { });
```

To avoid common pitfalls when combining click and drag handlers, you might want to have a look at Mike Bostock's [*Click vs. Drag*](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/a84aeb78fea81e1ad806) Block.